# nagios to watch lasso server

Tags: nagios

I'm using nagios to follow the workflow of my servers. Today one of my lasso server has been down and had to realize that nagios can not react in this case beacuse the server can be pinged even if is nagios is down. What would be a good workaround to can watch lasso activities with nagios. Is there a setup option in nagios to watch a html page?

Comment: http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http. What activities do you want to watch?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this lasso you are talking about, but you can use `check_http` plugin if you need to check for specific string in the response of an HTTP page.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make your own plugin to do a specific test.  Take a look at the core nagios manual.